# Android LibGDX setting projection matrix combined causes sprites to vertically flip over

Tags: java, android, libgdx

```
   public void render() {
        this.spriteRenderer.setProjectionMatrix(this.instance.camera.combined);
        this.spriteRenderer.begin();
        if (!this.ballon.isPoping()) {
            Sprite s = this.ballon.getSprite();
            spriteRenderer.draw(s, 50, 50, s.getWidth(), s.getHeight());
        }
//      else {
//          if (!this.ballon.isPoped()) {
//              Sprite s = this.ballon.getCurrentAnimation();
//              this.spriteRenderer.draw(s, this.ballon.getX(),
//                      this.ballon.getY(),
//                      this.ballon.getSprite().getWidth() * SpriteConfiguration.BALLON_SCALE,
//                      this.ballon.getSprite().getHeight() * SpriteConfiguration.BALLON_SCALE);                
//              this.ballon.processAnimation();
//          }
//      }
        this.spriteRenderer.end();
    }
```

I have set camera.setToOrtho to true with my width, and height. whenever I run that render method, my ballon sprite is basically vertically turned, looks like it flipped by 180 degrees over, like the image is saved as a standing ballon, and upon draw it looks like its turned, so I have to rotate the screen to see it.

The reason I used setProjectionMatrix is because the default location of the screen (0, 0) on android portrait mode I assume, is top-right corner, which on libGDX it is automtaically at bottom left corner, so basically setToOrtho fixes it for libGDX, but the phone's default location doesn't change, and I want it to change & be the same as libGDX's one because I need to handle screen touching, and get the correct position.

So basically setProjectionMatrix & setToOrtho(true...) does it's job, but the only problem that it just rotates the image by 180 degrees.

Does anyone know why it does that?

Comment: In Android's view system, (0,0) is in the top **left** corner, with Y pointing down. In libgdx, if you use `false` in `setToOrtho`, Y is up and (0,0) is in the bottom left corner. If you don't change the sprite batch's projection matrix at all, (0,0) is the center of the screen and you'll have a deformed aspect ratio. Are your individual sprites drawing sideways but in the correct locations on screen, or is the entire scene drawing sideways?

Comment: It doesn't matter what orientation you choose in `setToOrtho`. You can just use `camera.unproject()` to convert screen coordinates to a point in your scene coordinates, regardless of how the camera is set up.

Comment: If using `setToOrtho(true,...)`, I think you also want to use `flipY` when loading your sprites.